# Express request handler not typed when using express-validator

Tags: typescript, express-validator

When adding a express-validatorchain as middleware ts complains about the express request handler not being typed anymore.

[image: express-validator]

Using any other middleware works fine, when adding or removing the [] the error appears/dissappears.

[image: otherMiddleware]

```
"@types/express": "^4.17.6",
"typescript": "^3.9.5",
"express-validator": "^6.6.0",
```

As far as I am aware express-validator supports typescript out of the box, do I have to make any configuration changes in order for typescript to pick up the correct types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour happens due to the express typings not handling array handlers correctly.
See here: https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/869

A workaround to get these working is to spread the array (**...**) .

```
app.post("/route",...[myHandler,myHandler2],(req,res)=>{})
```